# how to catch an SMS not sent by the user manually? Any genius trick?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider

Since there are no broadcastReceiver for sent sms, we need to poll the SMS content provider (content://sms/sent) periodically and come up with a method to catch that a message was sent(onChange).
That is the easy part!

The tricky bit is, is it someway possible(may be an ingenious trick, hack, work around or even a loophole in the existing system) that can indicate whether the user sent the sms manually or it was sent automatically by some other installed app with a background service or a receiver triggered by some intent!

What say? Possible?

Comment: Only SMSes that are sent using the Native SMS app will appear in the `sent` table. Any app that sends using `SmsManager`, those smses are not recorded in the sent folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is sending SMS then you can get the status of SMS Sent or not as below. As you do not have global Call back for SMS not Sent you can not get know it.

```
    /**
 * Listen to Delivery Reports of sent SMSs
 */
private BroadcastReceiver mSmsDeliveryListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try{
            int result = getResultCode();
            switch (result){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    //SMS Delivered
                    break;

                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    //SMS Delivery failed
                    break;

                default:
        //SMS Delivery failed
                    break;
                }

            }//End of Switch
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question that was asked

Comment: As it is not possible to get sms not callback from system with out our own receiver,my answer holds some value is it not..

Comment: This is something that I was already aware of. My question still remains unsolved. Thnx for the reply anyway!